# Inline Editing row or cell

Tags: jquery, inline, editing

I want to develop a test project for inline editing using jQuery. In this I want to develop when ever I double click on a cell a text box of the column size instead of text or content, after user give input and press Enter Key the content of cell will be updated in database with previous value. But I haven't any idea how I can do it with jQuery. Can any one tell me about inline editing code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a jQuery question, why is it tagged with anything but jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable for the plugin Jeditable which gives you the behaviour you want to achive and adds some extra configuration options on top.

Answer (score 2):

Make an onclick event for each cell that replaces the content of the cell with a textbox with the cell's current value as default value. Make that input element have an onkeyup event that listens for the enter key and handles everything required when it's pressed.